# converting from deprecated cudnn functions to working ones

Tags: function, deprecated, cudnn

I need to run a repo that contains deprecated cudnn functions (cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm',cudnnGetConvolutionBackwardFilterAlgorithm','cudnnGetConvolutionBackwardDataAlgorithm'). I am on cudnn8.0 at the moment.

I know there are working versions of these functions: cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm_v7, cudnnGetConvolutionBackwardFilterAlgorithm_v7 etc but their parameters + return type change.

Do you have any advice on how I could convert from the deprecated version to the working version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't convert to the _v7 function, because you'll have to convert it again when support for it is removed altogether in a future version of the CUDNN library.  I'd be inclined to use the cudnnFind... functions, details of which are in the [cuDNN API Reference](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-api/index.html#cudnnFindConvolutionBackwardDataAlgorithm).  Since they actually test the possible algorithms that will be used and tell you the fastest one, they may give your network better performance than having a heuristic (used in cudnnGet...) which will only *probably* give you the fastest one.  There is an additional computation cost to call cudnnFind... when you create the network, but not to run it.  I haven't done testing yet to see how much extra time it takes, but I can't imagine it's anything noticeable.

Comment: I have since tested this with cuDNN 8.0.4 under CUDA 11.1.  The _v7 function works, but you have to give buffers for the number of algorithms to be returned and the performance results.  Not sure why they didn't leave the API the same.  The new version (cudnnFind...) works with the same parameters as you'd use for the _v7 function, but it does take a little time to do the calculations and find the best algorithm.